# A question of why these integrands can be taken out of the integrals.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, product-measure

Rudin says that (2) can be rewritten as (4), as seen below. However, both integrands in (2) respectively depend on $x$ and $y$, which implies that (2) could not be rewritten as (4). Is there any problem in my understanding? Thanks a lot.
[image]

Comment: The title of your question leads me to suspect that you've misunderstood the notation $\int d\mu(x)\,f(x)$. This is synonymous with $\int f(x)\,d\mu(x)$ and with $\int f\,d\mu$. No integrand (and nothing else either) is being taken out of integrals.

Comment: Yeah, actually I was guessing yours when writing the question. Thanks!